# Installing GSON JAR file and using it with Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, jar, gson

I am relatively new to Java and am using it with VS Code. I have downloaded the JAR file for GSON and I would like to use it in order to parse through a JSON structured string and assign it to string variables.

The only issue I am having is actually using the GSON api with the java class that reads through the JSON string and parses it. After downloading the JAR file, how do I import it into my java class that contains the readString method?

I am using VS Code as the IDE and am unable to find any documentation for VS Code

Any advice would be amazing!

Comment: If you're using an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, then check out the IDE-specific documentation on how to include jar files in your code's "build path"

Comment: Consider changing to a more Java-centric IDE, such as Eclipse.